# session_is_registered results in 404 - nginx

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with nginx it seems, I'm trying to use this code:

```
<?php session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(sessionvalue)){
header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Which is part of some simple login, as soon as I insert this in the page that is to be protected, I can't open it anymore and receive 404 Not Found. If I remove that bit of code it works without any hitch.

//Edit:
Turned out I was over PHP 5.4.0 so code has been changed to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionvalue'])
```

But the error persists, 404 not found.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? [`session_is_registered()`](http://php.net/session_is_registered) was DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: oh well, PHP 5.4.11, I really need to get my local server and remote server on the same versions :-( .. Thanks

Comment: @nickb I just changed it to: `if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionvalue'])` I still get the 404 error, any other idea ?

Comment: Do you have any other things going on? Like `.htaccess` rewrites or anything?

Comment: No, nothing like that

Comment: You realize that you're missing a closing parenthesis in this expression, right? `if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionvalue'])` needs to be `if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionvalue']))`

Answer (score 0):

Try /login.php instead of login.php

Also "Location", not "location".

Comment: same result, i ditched the header location completely for testing and just let it echo test instead, anyways, 404, so seems to be something with the `if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionvalue'])`